# how to fix my Error handling code? (tkinter GUI)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have split the error handing into 3 parts, ( check_black, raise_error, delete_error)

About about the functions:

> the check_blank() function checks if there are any errors in the input
> entries and raise_error() function raises the error by gridding() a
> ErrorLabel. and if the error have been resolved then delete_error()
> function deletes the error label.
>
> (there are 5 entry boxes and 4 check buttons, and a 'done' button)
> ( error should be raised if there's no input for all 5 Entries or at least one check button hasn't been checked )

this is the check_blanks() function:

```
 def checkblanks(self):
    flag = 0

    if not self.Text1.get():   #text.get() and Answer1.get() etc stores input from entry so if there's no entry then it will be empty
        flag = 1
    if not self.Answer1.get():
        flag = 1
    if not self.Answer2.get():
        flag = 1
    if not self.Answer3.get():
        flag = 1
    if not self.Answer4.get():
        flag = 1
    if not self.var.get():    # var.get stores input from check button so if its not checked then there won't be anything stored in var.get()
        flag += 2

    if flag == 0:     # flag = 0 means no error
        self.ErrorLabel = None

        self.add() #### EDIT ####
        self.delete_error()   
    elif flag == 1 or flag == 2 or flag == 3:   # if flag is 1 or 2 or 3 means there is error
        self.raise_error(flag)
```

> ```
>  flag 0 = means no errors
>  flag 1 = means that there's no input in all 5 entries
>  flag 2 = means at least one check button hasn't been checked
>  flag 3 = means both above errors occurred
> ```

this is the raise error_function:

```
 def raise_errors(self, flag):
    if flag == 1 or flag == 3:
        self.L5.grid_forget()
        self.ErrorLabel = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="Error: Fill all the blanks !", fg='white', bg='red')
        self.ErrorLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10)
    elif flag == 2:
        self.L5.grid_forget()
        self.ErrorLabel = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="Error: check ✔️ the correct answer ", fg='white', bg='red')
        self.ErrorLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10)
```

and the delete_error function:

```
   def delete_error(self):
    if self.ErrorLabel is not None:   # checks if the error label exists  
        self.ErrorLabel.grid_forget()
```

> but there is a problem:

> When the error is raised and then error label is made; after the
> errors are resolved then the error label is not deleted by
> delete_error()
>
> and sometimes multiple error labels overlap each other and it not very
> **efficient**
>
> I need to make the error handling functions more simple and work
> properly.

EDIT:

> also the function add() is called if flag == 0,( if there's no errors
> )                      the add() function just creates a new frame
> with the same entries and check buttons its and checks for errors all
> over again.
>
> its just a repeat loop

this is that function:

```
    def add(self):
        self.X += 1 
        self.frame2.grid_forget()    # deleted main frame
        self.amount_of_questions -= 1
        self.question(self.X)      # question() creates new frame with same widgets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is over writing each label because you are creating new label for each function call and so on, so I think its safe for us now, to get rid of `None` and try to use `config`:

```
def checkblanks(self):
    flag = 0
.....

    self.ErrorLabel = tk.Label(self.frame2,fg='white',bg='red') # Define the variable with basic base options
    if flag == 0:
        self.delete_error()   
    elif flag == 1 or flag == 2 or flag == 3:
        self.raise_error(flag)
```

and then `delete_error()` would be:

```
def delete_error(self):
    self.ErrorLabel.grid_forget() # Now always errorlabel is defined, you might want to use winfo_exists
```

So now you have to use `config` to update the widget inside `raise_errors()`:

```
def raise_errors(self, flag):
    if flag == 1 or flag == 3:
        self.L5.grid_forget()
        self.ErrorLabel.config(text="Error: Fill all the blanks !") # Update the widget
        self.ErrorLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10) # Grid it
    elif flag == 2:
        self.L5.grid_forget()
        self.ErrorLabel.config(text="Error: check ✔️ the correct answer ") # Update the widget
        self.ErrorLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10) # Grid it
```

Since I don't have a code to test this up with, this is based on imagination, I think you need `winfo_exists` inside `delete_errors()` too.

> after the errors are resolved then the error label is not deleted by delete_error()

This might be due to the way `self.ErrorLabel` was defined as `None`. Now that it is always defined as a `Label`, it should be fine.

EDIT: Can you try moving the label inside of `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    ....

    self.ErrorLabel = tk.Label(self.frame2,fg='white',bg='red')
```

Comment: this works but the 2nd error label ( flag == 2) doesn't get deleted when error is resolved,    also I made a small edit about a another function being called.

Comment: @coder_not_found How does the `flag` change, how does it know that the error is resolved?

Comment: I forgot to mention check_blanks is called every time the 'done button' is pressed and check_blanks function changes the flag accordingly

Comment: @coder_not_found Use `print()` and find out if code execution reaches inside `delete_error()` or if it goes inside the `elif` and triggers `raise_errors()`

Comment: it apparently reaches inside delete_error when there's no error but it doesn't delete it (only the second error label doesn't get deleted).

Comment: @coder_not_found Try the edited version, make sure you remove it from `check_blanks()` and put it inside `__init__`.

Comment: yes finally it works,  just one question: how do I make entry boxes blank when grid() because previously entered input is still on the entry boxe

Comment: @coder_not_found Hmmm, `entryname.delete(0,'end')`.